# How can I make 3 plots show on 3 radio buttons with their own captions?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am currently making an app for class using shiny and I currently have 3 radio buttons set up with an if else statment selecting them.  My first issue is that my code will not run properly which I believe is an issue if the else part of my if else statement.  Additionally if it will run properly I want to add captions to each of these plots.  Please help

```
ui = function(){
  fluidPage(
    radioButtons( "type", "", c( "Decomposition", "Seasonality","AFC" )),
    plotOutput( "plot" ))
}

server <-  function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req( input$type ) # Plot type required
    
    if( input$type == "Decomposition" )
       VOLS %>%
              model(classical_decomposition(Interest, type = "multiplicative"))%>%
              components()%>%
              autoplot() 
      
    if(input$type =="Seasonality")
      plot(gg_season(VOLS))
    else
      plot( ggAcf(VOLS) + ggtitle("ACF of VOLS") )
    )}
)

shinyApp( ui, server )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your if else statements in curly brackets.

```
server <-  function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req( input$type ) # Plot type required
    
    if( input$type == "Decomposition" ){
      VOLS %>%
        model(classical_decomposition(Interest, type = "multiplicative"))%>%
        components()%>%
        autoplot() 
    } else if {
      plot(gg_season(VOLS))
    } else {
      plot( ggAcf(VOLS) + ggtitle("ACF of VOLS") )
    }
  })
}
```